# What verb tense does the phrase "is been living" belong to?

Tags: verbs, present-perfect, present-tense, tenses

I have seen the following phrase:

> We're been living here since April.

And I'm confused what is the verb tense that is used here. I thought it might be **Present Perfect Continuous**, which is a replacement for:

> We've been living here since April.

Hence, I conclude the following two phrases are the same:

> We're living here since April.
>   We've been living here since April.

Am I correct? If no, then would you please explain it?

Comment: Typo. Should be "*we've* been living...". There is no "we are been living".

Comment: Look at the famous book "Practical English Usage" and you see there is such phrase...

Comment: I don't have the book, sorry. Furthermore, if it's in there, it's *still wrong*. If it's there in ten years, it will be wrong then as well. I've been speaking English for decades. There is no "we are been living".

Comment: She's quite right.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misapprehension.

Comment: @medica has it right. **DO NOT BELIEVE WHAT "ENGLISH BOOKS" SAY.** They are written by people who know nothing about English grammar and bought by people who know even less. Throw it away or kindle a fire with it. You can't learn English from any book. You need to speak with native speakers.

Comment: By the way, **335,000 results** https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=%22we+are+been%22+

Comment: "So I heard bad grammar is what we are been doing write now?" (Found this gem on the web.)

Comment: @MostafaTalebi. On which page did you find the sentence in Swan's book? I can find it in none of the obvious places. If it is there, then it is surely a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *We're been living here since April.*

**are been (verb)-ing** is a literal borrowing from the syntax of the speaker's native language. Some European and other languages follow this structure and one unfamiliar with the English structure tends to unconsciously use it in English.

One can find lots of examples in Indian English today.